# Как найти субтитры в коде страницы?

Tags: html

Нужно извлечь субтитры из потокового видео. Субтитры не вшиты, тк есть возможность переключить язык субтитров. Пробую найти в коде страницы ссылки на ресурсы с расширением .srt .vtt, просто ищу subtitles, но ссылку найти не могу. Может, есть еще способы?

Ссылка на сайт, код которого смотрела https://megogo.ru/ru/view/9882-krot-sezon-1-seriya-6.html?video_view_tab=description

Нахожу только субтитр, который в данный момент виден в видео. Скриншот прикладываю. [image: .]

Comment: класс PlayerSkinStyled__Subtitles-sc-1qej3qy-26 lbnRVd, там слова вставляются в div с этим классом, он удаляется/добавляется (сам блок)

Comment: _Субтитры не вшиты, тк есть возможность переключить язык субтитров_ - из второго совсем не следует первое.

Comment: Титры подгружаются динамически, в зависимости от позиции воспроизведения. Определённо есть где-то файл с титрами или какая-то БД, но конкретно на страницу это попадает частями.